# Filter an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have data that looks like this:

```
[{address: '1300 BRYANT ST',
  block: '3903',
  cnn: '517000',
  latitude: '37.7690871267671',
  longitude: '-122.411527667132',
  received: '2016-05-06',
  x: '6009188.668',
  y: '2108146.472' }, {B...}, {C...}]
```

I want to filter the data to look like this:

```
[{address: '1300 BRYANT ST',
  latitude: '37.7690871267671',
  longitude: '-122.411527667132'},
  ...]
```

How do I filter this data using JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to do this is with the [array `.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var arr = [{address: '1300 BRYANT ST', block: '3903', cnn: '517000', latitude: '37.7690871267671', longitude: '-122.411527667132', received: '2016-05-06', x: '6009188.668', y: '2108146.472' }, {address: '12 ANOTHER ST', block: '3903', cnn: '517000', latitude: '12.7690871299999', longitude: '44.412300067132', received: '2016-05-06', x: '6009188.668', y: '2108146.472' }];

arr = arr.map(function(v) {
    return {
      address: v.address,
      latitude: v.latitude,
      longitude: v.longitude
    };
  });

console.log(arr);
```

In the code shown I've assigned the result back to the same variable, but you could assign it to a new variable if you need to keep a reference to the original full data.

By the way, regarding the original wording of your question, you don't have a "JSON object", because [there is no such thing](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/): you have either an object (in your specific case an array of objects), or JSON (as a string that needs to be parsed). What you show in your question is not valid JSON because JSON requires double-quotes not single-quotes, and property names must be quoted, but it is valid JS object literal syntax.

If your data actual is JSON, a *string*, then you would first parse it, then manipulate the resulting array. (And if you actually need it as JSON after that you'd re-stringify the result.)

```
var json = /* your string here */
var arr = JSON.parse(json);
// map here as above
var updateJson = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Comment: You are redeclaring `arr`. It would probably be better to just assign `arr = arr.map(...)`.

Comment: @SumnerEvans - Good point. I started out assigning the result to a new variable, then changed it to overwrite the old one. Updated.

Comment: @nnnnnn : Actually, I updated my array, the keys are also strings. How would that change this javascript code? Thank you!!!

Comment: It wouldn't change it at all. If you create an object with `{someKey: 1}` (no quotes) the actual key will be the string `"someKey"`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have parsed your JSON to a JavaScript object called `jsonData`, you can just iterate the array and add like so:

```
var jsonData = ...;

var filteredData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    filteredData.push({
        address: jsonData[i].address,
        latitude: jsonData[i].latitude,
        longitude: jsonData[i].longitude,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using plain JavaScript:

```
var arr=
[{address: '1300 BRYANT ST',
  block: '3903',
  cnn: '517000',
  latitude: '37.7690871267671',
  longitude: '-122.411527667132',
  received: '2016-05-06',
  x: '6009188.668',
  y: '2108146.472' }];

var k=arr.map(function(v) {
    return {
        address: v.address,
        latitude: v.latitude,
        longitude: v.longitude
    }
});
```

Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/halimmln/pen/GjjLQE).